How to align multiple card contents using a grid layout using Tailwindcss?
I'm trying to align some elements inside cards inside a grid with Tailwindcss, I've tried to follow this answer that it's pretty much what I intend
Aligning elements on CSS Grid Layout Cards
This answer is for plain CSS, so I think I must be doing something wrong in Tailwind because I can't replicate it. I'm also using Laravel, forget the loop here, its for not repeating the divs inside the grid over and over. I also drop lots of classes that are not related to the problem.
  @foreach ($eventos as $evento)
    <article class="flex flex-col">

      <!-- Cover image -->
      <div
        class="flex items-end justify-end w-full h-48 bg-top bg-cover rounded-t-lg"
        style="background-image: url('{{ $evento->avatar }}');"
        >
        <x-gui.badge
          color="info"
          size="xs"
          >
          {{ $evento->tipo_juego }}
        </x-gui.badge>
      </div>

      <!-- Content -->
      <div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-dark rounded-b-xl grow">
        <h5 class="h-16 mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-dark dark:text-light">{{ $evento->nombre }}</h5>

        <p class="grow">{{ $evento->descripcion }}</p>

        <x-gui.button
          color="info"
          size="xs"
          class="mt-4"
          >
          {{ $evento->tipo_juego }}
        </x-gui.button>
      </div>
    </article>
  @endforeach


I want to align the buttons at the bottom. I'd also like if possible that all the card titles are the same height

The <p class="grow">{{ $evento->descripcion }}</p> has class grow but the parent is not flex so it is not working.
Try adding class flex flex-col to <div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 text-dark rounded-b-xl grow">
